# safe use of iterator in syncronized collections

Tags: java, collections, iterator, synchronization

In tutorial about synchronizedMap I faced following code(comments from tutorial):

```
Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
...
Set s = m.keySet();  // Needn't be in synchronized block
...
synchronized(m) {  // Synchronizing on m, not s!
    Iterator i = s.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
    while (i.hasNext())
          foo(i.next());
}
```

I saw in source code that iterator methods is not wrapped by synchronized section. It is ok.

I am afraid to get something unexpected

```
Set s = m.keySet();  
// Could happen something unexpected here ?
synchronized(m) {
```

Please clarify why does this code is safety?

```
 synchronized(m) {  // Synchronizing on m, not s!
        Set s = m.keySet();  // Needn't be in synchronized block
        Iterator i = s.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
        while (i.hasNext())
              foo(i.next());
    }
```

Does this syncronization excessive ?

Answer (score 0):

While `Collections.synchronizedMap()` guarantees that each operation on the wrapped map is thread safe, it does not guarantee that iterating over it is. When you synchronize on the map while iterating, you're guaranteeing that another thread cannot access the map while 1 thread is iterating over it (after all, you want to make sure that you iterate over it in an atomic fashion).

Without this synchronization, another thread could perform one or more operations between the `i.hasNext()` while-loop.

The implementation is that `synchronizedMap()` wrapper syncs on the collection itself (in your code `m`), so getting the object monitor with `synchronized(m)` makes sure that another thread cannot access it before the iteration has been performed completely.

Comment: I am afraid about operations between *Set s = m.keySet();*  and *Iterator i = s.iterator()*

Comment: Why are you afraid about them? If there are changes in the keyset, they will be reflected in `s`. If you want to avoid that, you should synchronize on `m` before you take the keyset out.

Comment: I cannot to imagine all changes which can happen.

Comment: Well any changes related to the keyset. Adding and removing items mainly I'd say.